# assign ten 10 rows of values into a single row[0] using python

Tags: python-3.6

I have a dataFrame df=  LON   LAT    COG     SOG
                        32.1  44.5   30.2    56.5 shape is 540x4.

Now i need to split the data based on the below requirements.

1) row[0] to row[9] into a single row (i.e. 1st row: Output should be one Row. row size will be 1x40 )

2) row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJJwl.png) to row[10] into a single row(i.e. 2nd row: Output should be one Row. row size will be 1x40)

3) row[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcOHS.png) to row[11] is (3nd row: Output should be one Row. row size will be 1x40) till 540

4) Final output shape will be 540x40.

5) For better understanding attached input and output images.

[input_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJJwl.png)

[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcOHS.png)

Comment: please show the df your working with and an expected output

Comment: image added for input_data and Output_data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

Get the columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (20, 4)))
columns = df.columns.tolist() * 10
```

Iterate over your current df and concat each rows

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    ndf = pd.DataFrame(df[i: i + 10].values.flatten(), columns).T
    tdf = pd.concat([tdf, ndf])
```

Finally reset the index

`df = tdf.reset_index(drop=True)`